# How do I set typescript types for an AWS amplify GraphQL response in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I have a react component in typescript and I want to set the results of an appsync graphql query to a property in state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import {ListProjectsQuery} from './API'
import {listProjects } from './graphql/queries';

class App extends Component<{}, {
  projects:ListProjectsQuery
}>  {
  state = {
    projects: null
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const projects = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listProjects));
    this.setState({ projects });
  }

  ...
```

How do I define the default state property to make this work?

I found [a similar problem](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2646) in the amplify github issues but that solution was in the context of a stateless functional component. I am using a stateful component.

Depending on what I try I seem to get one of three errors.

The code above throws `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ListProjectsQuery'.`.

This makes sense so I try and map the shape in state like so:

```
state = {
    projects: {listProjects: {items: [{name: ''}]}}
  }
```

which makes it throw `Types of property 'projects' are incompatible.`

I either get told that a `Property does not exist on type 'Observable<object>'` or I get told the shape of the default state value is not compatible.

Finally I tried to use an interface like in the example I found:

```
interface IListProjectQuery {
  projects: ListProjectsQuery;
}
```

and then I reference the interface

```
class App extends Component<
  {},
  {
    projects: IListProjectQuery;
  }
>
```

and it throws the following error `Type '{ projects: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ projects: IListProjectQuery; }>'.`

**What value do I give the default state property in order for it to make typescript happy?**

The `ListProjectsQuery` import is autogenerated by amplify/appsync codegen, the type alias looks like so:

```
export type ListProjectsQuery = {
  listProjects:  {
    __typename: "ModelProjectConnection",
    items:  Array< {
      __typename: "Project",
      id: string,
      name: string,
      organisation:  {
        __typename: "Organisation",
        id: string,
        name: string,
      } | null,
      list:  {
        __typename: "ModelListConnection",
        nextToken: string | null,
      } | null,
    } | null > | null,
    nextToken: string | null,
  } | null,
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You have to define a type that matches the structure of data you are expecting from amplify
- The second step is to cast your response data as the type you defined and that's it.
- Your projects property inside your state should be properly typed, **projects: IProject[ ] | undefined** . You either have an array of projects or it's undefined.

```js
export type IProject = {
    name: string
}

export type GetProjectsQuery = {
    listProjects:{
        items: IProject[]
        nextToken: string
    }
}

const fetchAllProjects = async () => {
    try {
      const result = (await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listProjects))) as {
        data: GetProjectsQuery
      }
      projects = result.data.listProjects.items
      

    } catch (error) {
      //handle error here 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your property optional:

```
class App extends Component<{}, {
  projects?: ListProjectsQuery //<<== note the question mark
}>  {
  state = {
    projects: null
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const projects = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listProjects));
    this.setState({ projects });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatley this didn't help. It throws `Property 'state' in type 'App' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Component<{}, { projects?: ListProjectsQuery | undefined; }, any>'.` So switched null to undefined in component state and then it went back to throwing `Types of property 'projects' are incompatible.`

Comment: The complete error log for the latter is:
```
Type error: Argument of type '{ projects: GraphQLResult | Observable<object>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ projects?: ListProjectsQuery | undefined; } | ((prevState: Readonly<{ projects?: ListProjectsQuery | undefined; }>, props: Readonly<{}>) => { projects?: ListProjectsQuery | undefined; } | Pick<...> | null) | Pick<...> | null'.
  Type '{ projects: GraphQLResult | Observable<object>; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<{ projects?: ListProjectsQuery | undefined; }, "projects">'.
    ``` continued...

Comment: ```Types of property 'projects' are incompatible.
      Type 'GraphQLResult | Observable<object>' is not assignable to type 'ListProjectsQuery | undefined'.
        Property 'listProjects' is missing in type 'GraphQLResult' but required in type 'ListProjectsQuery'.  TS2345``````

Comment: either you cast the type of the result manually like const projects = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listProjects)) as ListProjectsQuery; or . you have to add another type to the result, as it is possible, the query does not resolve and then the type will not be of type ListProjectsQuery, but undefined, or e.g. an error type.

Comment: Sadly I have run into this problem as well. I think the answer may be to not use `async / await`.. then you should be able to type it more easily right? I think i will just cast the response..